# Operator norm comparison

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For Hilbert space $H$ and bounded linear operator $L\in B(H)$, let the definition of $\lVert L \rVert$ be $$\sup_{\lVert u \rVert \neq 0} \frac{\lVert Lu \rVert}{\lVert u \rVert}$$

Now if we let $N=\sup\{|\langle Lu, u \rangle|: \lVert u \rVert=1\}$, how to show that $N \leq \lVert L \rVert$ and if $H$ is complex then $N \leq \lVert L \rVert \leq 2N$?

(We have an identity:  $\langle L(u+αv), u+αv\rangle − \langle L(u-αv), u-αv\rangle = 2α\langle Lu,v\rangle+2α\langle Lv,u\rangle$)

Comment: Use the fact that $\langle a,b\rangle \leq \|a\|\|b\|$?

Comment: @user7530 It can make $\langle Lu, u\rangle \leq \lVert Lu \rVert \lVert u \rVert$, but for $\lVert Lu \rVert$ itself, seems no progress can be made.

Comment: I edited to change $\langle Lu, u \rangle$ to $|\langle Lu, u \rangle|$ in the definition of $N$, since it makes no sense to take suprema of nonreal complex numbers.  If this was not your intention, please change it back.

Comment: @Aweygan It is indeed a typo, thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but don't you just have
$$\|L\| = \sup_{\|u\|\neq 0} \frac{\|Lu\|}{\|u\|} = \sup_{\|u\|=1} \|Lu\| = \sup_{\|u\|=1} \|Lu\|\|u\| \geq \sup_{\|u\|=1} |\langle Lu, u\rangle|?$$

Comment: @user7530 Yeah it's right, I found this apart just now. Wasn't sure what you were referring at the beginning. Thanks.